# Use diferent values in helm deploy through Terraform (for_each)

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm using 0.14.7 terraform version and 1.3.2 Helm provider.

I'm trying to deploy the same chart application with different values file and different namespace like totally independent applications:

```
resource "helm_release" "kong-deploy" {
  for_each   =  var.country

  chart      = "./helm-charts/kong"
  name       = "kong"
  namespace  = "each.value.country"
  create_namespace = true
  version    = "2.0"
  timeout = 60
  values = [
    file("./helm-values/${local.environment}/kong-${local.environment}-${each.value.country}.yaml")
  ]
}
```

And here are the tfvars:

```
country = {
    spain = "es"
    united_kingdom = "uk"
}
```

The expected result is that helm-release use the `kong-pre-es/uk.yml` file.

But whe I'm doing the terraform plan, I'm getting the next error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on deploy.tf line 11, in resource "helm_release" "kong-deploy":
  11:     file("./helm-values/${local.environment}/kong-${local.environment}-${each.value.country}.yaml")
    |----------------
    | each.value is "es"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on deploy.tf line 11, in resource "helm_release" "kong-deploy":
  11:     file("./helm-values/${local.environment}/kong-${local.environment}-${each.value.country}.yaml")
    |----------------
    | each.value is "uk"
```

I don't know where is the error.. Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this example, you are iterating over a Map with key-value pairs `"spain" = "es", "united_kingdom" = "uk"`. In your scope, the temporary lambda iterator variable `each.key` is assigned the current iterator's key for Map iteration, and `each.value` is assigned the current iterator's value for Map iteration.

For example, in the first iteration, `each.key` would be assigned `spain`, and `each.value` would be assigned `es`.

Assuming that you want the country name in `each.value.country`, then this is the key in your Map, and you would update like:

```
values = [file("./helm-values/${local.environment}/kong-${local.environment}-${each.key}.yaml")]
```

and that will resolve to a suffix of `spain.yml` in the first iteration.

If instead you want the language name, then this is the value in your Map, and you would update like:

```
values = [file("./helm-values/${local.environment}/kong-${local.environment}-${each.value}.yaml")]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. No, I would like to get the value, and if you see the output error the iteration get the values 'es' and 'uk'.. The problem is why I got this error if the iteration is correct.. ?

Comment: Anyway, if I use each.value.country, I got same error :(

Comment: @hmar Ok given that you wanted the language and not the country, I have updated the answer for code for that situation as well. My answer already explained how to to fix the error, but I have added exact code if you want to copy and paste.