# Diff values file using helm provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I hope you can help me light some more light on my issue.

Currently I'm using:

- Terraform v1.3.5
- Helm provider v2.8.0
- Kubernetes provider v2.16.1

Lately I've been adapting the helm provider on Terraform, to help me manage Helm releases with more resiliency. It helps a lot to be able to `plan` changes and see what has changed and what remains the same. It merges really well with the infrastructure details and I can manage everything with just one tool, it has been great.

There is one thing that bothers me a little. It's the `terraform plan` preview of the values file, it just shows you that some changes have been made, but not where or which. Let me add an example.

File `main.tf`:

```
# I'm using the "manifest" setting to calculate manifest diffs
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path    = "~/.kube/config"
    config_context = "clusterconfig"
  }
  experiments {
    manifest = true
  }
}

# The helm chart lives locally on my repo. I'm passing the values file and an
#  override for the image tag.
resource "helm_release" "release" {
  name      = "example"
  chart     = "../../helm/chart"
  namespace = "example"
  wait      = true
  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = "latest"
  }
  values = [
    file("helm/values-example.yaml")
  ]
}
```

This works great, the problem comes when I make a change on the values file. It shows the whole file instead of just the changes. For example in my values file I change the replicas from 1 to 2:

File `values-example.yaml`:

```yaml
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: test
  pullPolicy: ifNotPresent
```

The execution:

```bash
$ terraform plan
(...)
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # helm_release.example will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "helm_release" "example" {
      ~ manifest       = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ "deployment.apps/apps/v1/deployname"      = {
                  ~ spec       = {
                      - replicas = 1 -> 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
  ~ values                     = [
    - <<-EOT
    replicaCount: 1
    image:
      repository: test
      pullPolicy: ifNotPresent
    EOT,
    + <<-EOT
    replicaCount: 2
    image:
      repository: test
      pullPolicy: ifNotPresent
    EOT,
  ]
```

This makes it very difficult to see which values settings have been changed, when the values file is bigger.

**So then, my question**, do you know if there is a way to diff the values? I would like to see only the changes instead of the whole file.

What I've seen online:

- It's been asked for on GitHub, but closed https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/305
- Maybe something like this can be implemented: [Use diferent values in helm deploy through Terraform (for_each)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259007/use-diferent-values-in-helm-deploy-through-terraform-for-each?newreg=10e2602409f1472abf1bfc560c39986c)

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if I can help with any more information.